# How do I change the inequality representation in PORTA output?

Tags: vertex, convex-hull, quantum-computing, inequality

I am trying to derive facet Bell Inequalities given the extreme points of a 16-dim polytope. I have been using the software PORTA to go from the standard vertex representation to the inequality representation. However, my PORTA output seems to give inequalities(the bottom inequalities (17)-(24) are the main ones I'm looking for) which are stated in terms of eight equalities((1) - (8) above in the picture). I used the traf.bat function. I was wondering is there any way to make PORTA simply give me eight inequalities dependent on the 16 unknown variables and not in terms of the eight equalities above? These inequalities should end up looking like the familiar CHSH inequalities where you have 16 unknowns <= 2.
[Picture showing the given inequalities and equalities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW4t6.png)